# Submit Only if a specific button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form like:

```
<form id='Contact' action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset='UTF-8' style='background-color:#7FFF00; width: 781px'>
```

In that form, I have 15 fields. The first three "FirstName", "Title", "LastName" are the only three required for the form to submit.

The form has three buttons. One for deleting, creating, and modifying.

When Create is clicked, it has to validate the three fields and then submit the form.
When Delete is clicked, it only has to validate one specific field and then submit.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function validateForm(Form, FieldName)
{
    var Form = document.getElementById(Form);
    var Elements = Form.elements;
    var Field = Elements[FieldName].value;

    if (Field == null || Field == "")
    {
        alert(FieldName + " must be filled out!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function SubmitForm(Form, DoSubmit)
{
    if (DoSubmit)
    {
        document.getElementById(Form).submit();
    }
}
-->
</script>
```

My CreateButton:

```
<input type='button' name='ContactInfo' value='Create' onClick="SubmitForm('Contact', validateForm('Contact', 'Title') && validateForm('Contact', 'FirstName') && validateForm('Contact', 'LastName'));" />
```

My Delete Button:

```
<input type='submit' name='ContactInfo' value='Delete' />
```

Why does the Create Button not work? It validates the required fields but does NOT submit/Post :S

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: Yes. It clears the form and everything. It just doesn't Post. If I change the button type to Submit type then it will Post and I won't be able to keep the data in the form. I need it so that if it validates then it can post. If it fails validation, it should do nothing.

Comment: Have you tried turning the type from 'button' to 'submit'? You want it to submit the form but you've not specified it as a submit button..

Comment: For readability you're probably better off making a create function that does the validation and then calls submit form if the form validates.  I would guess you're trying to do too much inside of an onClick attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try the following.


<input type='submit' name='ContactInfo' value='Create' onClick="SubmitForm('Contact', validateForm('Contact', 'Title') && validateForm('Contact', 'FirstName') && validateForm('Contact', 'LastName'));return false;" />
```

change the type to submit and put a return false at the end.

or add this to your form element:

```
onsubmit="return validateForm(this);"
```

and do tests for Delete etc.. if this.value === "Delete" etc...

Comment: Ahh this worked! The return Statement works. I did If (WhatYouSaidAbove) return true; else return false; and that worked.

Comment: great, glad it worked. Can you accept when timer is up :-) , trying to up my rep! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have `document.getElementById(Form)` when the ID of your form is "Contact". So change that to `document.getElementById("Contact")`.